# Slackbot Deployment via ECS

Tags: devops, slack, aws-ecs, blue-green-deployment, chatops

I have a slackbot that uses RTM api and it's currently deployed via AWS ECS. Whenever I want to update the bot, a new task comes in and there's a 10-20 second window where the old bot is still shutting down while the new bot is up so now there will be two bots creating duplicate actions.

Is there a way to do "Blue-Green" deployment with this scenario. ALB - ECS "Blue-Green" wouldn't work in my case since the bots are reading inputs from RTM instead of receiving traffic.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!